# C++ template doesn't improve performance

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

I implemented three versions of bubble sort with loop unrolling (LU) to study c++ template. i.e., without loop unrolling, manual loop unrolling with C macro, and loop unrolling with template. Code:

```
// No LU
void bubbleSort(int* data, int n)
{
    for(int i=n-1; i>0; --i) {
        for(int j=0; j<i; ++j)
            if (data[j]>data[j+1]) std::swap(data[j], data[j+1]);
    }
}
// LU with macro
void bubbleSort4(int* data)
{
#define COMP_SWAP(i, j) if(data[i]>data[j]) std::swap(data[i], data[j])
    COMP_SWAP(0, 1); COMP_SWAP(1, 2); COMP_SWAP(2, 3);
    COMP_SWAP(0, 1); COMP_SWAP(1, 2);
    COMP_SWAP(0, 1);
}
// LU with template
template<int i, int j>
inline void IntSwap(int* data) {
    if(data[i]>data[j]) std::swap(data[i], data[j]);
}
template<int i, int j>
inline void IntBubbleSortLoop(int* data) {
    IntSwap<j, j+1>(data);
    IntBubbleSortLoop<j<i-1?i:0, j<i-1?(j+1):0>(data);
}
template<>
inline void IntBubbleSortLoop<0, 0>(int*) { }
template<int n>
inline void IntBubbleSort(int* data) {
    IntBubbleSortLoop<n-1, 0>(data);
    IntBubbleSort<n-1>(data);
}
template<>
inline void IntBubbleSort<1>(int* data) { }
```

Test code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>  //std::swap
#include <string.h> // memcpy
#include <sys/time.h>

class Timer{
    struct timeval start_t;
    struct timeval end_t;
    public: 
    void start() { gettimeofday(&start_t, NULL); }
    void end() { gettimeofday(&end_t, NULL); }
    void print() {
        std::cout << "Timer: " << 1000.0*(end_t.tv_sec-start_t.tv_sec)+(end_t.tv_usec-start_t.tv_usec)/1000.0 << " ms\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    Timer t1, t2, t3; const int num=100000000;
    int data[4]; int inidata[4]={3,4,2,1};

    t1.start();
    for(int i=0; i<num; ++i) { 
        memcpy(data, inidata, 4); 
        bubbleSort(data, 4); 
    }
    t1.end();
    t1.print();

    t2.start();
    for(int i=0; i<num; ++i) { 
        memcpy(data, inidata, 4); 
        bubbleSort4(data); 
    }
    t2.end();
    t2.print();

    t3.start();
    for(int i=0; i<num; ++i) { 
        memcpy(data, inidata, 4); 
        IntBubbleSort<4>(data);    
    }
    t3.end();
    t3.print();

    return 0;
}
```

My platform is OSX, and the compiler is clang:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -o loop_unrolling loop_unrolling.cpp
```

I expect the template version has similar performance with macro verison, which is much faster than the normal one. However, the template version is the slowest. Anybody know why?

```
Timer: 1847.78 ms
Timer: 685.736 ms
Timer: 5075.86 ms
```

=================================

with -O1:

```
Timer: 861.071 ms
Timer: 495.001 ms
Timer: 2793.02 ms
```

with -O2:

```
Timer: 247.691 ms
Timer: 258.666 ms
Timer: 254.466 ms
```

with -O3:

```
Timer: 242.535 ms
Timer: 233.354 ms
Timer: 251.297 ms
```

What confuses me is, template version should generate loop unrolling code no matter whether I enable -Ox or not. But it looks not true. What confuses me more is, it is even slower than the non-LP version while not enable -Ox.

Comment: Optimization level used when compiling is actually?

Comment: I think these "why is my code slow" questions that do not also have what optimization levels are being used deserve a downvote.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie You're probably right. That requirement falls into [MCVE], doesn't it?

Comment: So your asking... Why C++ is the way it is?

Comment: Your commandline for compiling (as shown) doesn't enable the optimizer, so performance comparisons are pointless. Try it with `-O2` or `-O3`.

Comment: @OP  Change your options to turn on optimizations (the `-Ox` option).   The numbers you posted are meaningless, the "loop unrolling" you mentioned in your question becomes meaningless, etc. if you don't enable optimizations.

Comment: Upvoted the question since I believe it's a fair enough question. Just because the OP doesn't seem to know about the optimizer is not a reason to downvote - the question was well put. We should educate rather than downvote fair questions.

Comment: @JesperJuhl But the OP has yet to respond to the request.  Upvote once they respond.  We've led the horse to water, but refuses to drink.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, I assume, OP meant to say that their code is attempting to perform manual loop unrolling - and this is what OP is measuring.

Comment: With [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/393e49e72b04dac9), I got a difference of 100ms for the same code, so the mesures are not really reliable.

Comment: In not optimized builds, your template version does a lot of function calls.

Comment: @Jarod42 Could you tell why? AFAIK, all template function calls within templates are unfolded recursively during compiling time instead of runtime.  so, the runtime should not incur a lot of function calls.

Comment: @BugRepairMan: with optimization your calls can indeed be inlined (which seems be the case from `-O2`). but your template once intantiated do really something like `template<>
void IntBubbleSortLoop<3, 1>(int* data) {
    IntSwap<1, 2>(data);
    IntBubbleSortLoop<3, 2>(data);
}`

Comment: @Jarod42: Thanks. Now I understand why lots of calls.  Function templates are inline functions. But inline functions are not always expansion, as compiler can ignore 'inline'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jarod42 has pointed out your problem is function calls. The compiler process that generates functions from function templates is separate to the compiler process that does inlining. As a result inlining is not guaranteed and you pay the performance penalty of the function calls in the template version. Please note that the `inline` keyword is a hint to compiler which it is not obligated to respect.

If you have a similar problem in the future and are feeling brave, you can look at the assembly code generated by your code to see differences. Taking your code above and splitting it into two compilation units b4.cc

```
// b4.cc
#include <algorithm>

// LU with macro
void bubbleSort4(int* data)
{
#define COMP_SWAP(i, j) if(data[i]>data[j]) std::swap(data[i], data[j])
    COMP_SWAP(0, 1); COMP_SWAP(1, 2); COMP_SWAP(2, 3);
    COMP_SWAP(0, 1); COMP_SWAP(1, 2);
    COMP_SWAP(0, 1);
}
```

and b4t.cc

```
// b4t.cc
#include <algorithm>

// LU with template
template<int i, int j>
inline void IntSwap(int* data) {
    if(data[i]>data[j]) std::swap(data[i], data[j]);
}
template<int i, int j>
inline void IntBubbleSortLoop(int* data) {
    IntSwap<j, j+1>(data);
    IntBubbleSortLoop<j<i-1?i:0, j<i-1?(j+1):0>(data);
}
template<>
inline void IntBubbleSortLoop<0, 0>(int*) { }
template<int n>
inline void IntBubbleSort(int* data) {
    IntBubbleSortLoop<n-1, 0>(data);
    IntBubbleSort<n-1>(data);
}
template<>
inline void IntBubbleSort<1>(int* data) { }

// LU with macro
void bubbleSort4(int* data)
{
    IntBubbleSort<4>(data);
}
```

This allows you to then `g++ -S b4*.cc` and compare b4.s and b4t.s. Notice that b4t.s is filled with many functions. Whereas when you turning on inlining such as in `g++ -O2 -S b4*.cc` the assembly is effectively identical.

Comment: Thanks. Now I know 'inline' is not compulsion.